# Oracle -Assign Monday to Sunday week for the week number for calendar date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the data from 01 Jan 2019 - Present. I want to assign week numbers to the date column. The week should start on Monday and end on Sunday.

But the function I use starts from 01 Jan 2019 (Tuesday) as week 1 start date for the following
    to_number(to_char(to_date(CALENDAR_D, 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'ww'))

If I replace 'ww' with 'iw', then it starts with first thursday of the week.

I want the cycle to be Monday to Sunday with the first monday of the year 2019 to be my first day of my first week.

Expected Output

```
Calendar_d       Week Number
01/01/2019        Any Number (Tuesday)
01/02/2019        Any Number
01/03/2019        Any Number
01/04/2019        Any Number
01/05/2019        Any Number
01/06/2019        Any Number (Sunday)
01/07/2019            1
01/08/2019            1
01/09/2019            1
01/10/2019            1
01/11/2019            1
01/12/2019            1
01/13/2019            1
01/14/2019            2
```

Comment: So, the expected output has exactly those rows, from 1 January to 14 January? Not for the entire year 2019? Do you want to show Any Number for January 1? That doesn't make a lot of sense; you can leave it `null`, or show it as `0` (indicating that 1 January was not on Monday), or compute it as a number from 2018.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next_day()` and date arithmetic:

```
select floor((datecol - next_day(date '2019-01-01', 'Monday')) / 7) + 1 as weeknum
```

Or, if this is in a table, you can use window functions:

```
select t.datecol,
       sum(case when to_char(datecol, 'DY') = 'MON' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by to_char(datecol, 'YYYY') order by t.datecol) as weeknum
from t
where t.datecol >= date '2019-01-01'
```

Comment: The partition doesn't do a sequence in your script .

Comment: @Virat . . . I don't know what you mean by that comment.

Comment: Like the week should start from 1 and then go on sequencial. the first week should be 01/07/2019 - 01/14/2019 and second week should be 01/15/2019 - 01/22/2019 etc.

Comment: @Virat . . . It should do that, assuming you have a table of dates.

Comment: Careful with `next_day` since it doesn't return "today" if "today" is a Monday; it does literally return **next** date that is a Monday. Use `'2018-12-31'` instead of `'2019-01-01'`.